# Spark program performance - GC & Task Deserialization & Concurrent execution

Tags: scala, apache-spark, garbage-collection, apache-spark-sql, concurrent-programming

I have a cluster of 4 machines, 1 master and three workers, each with 128G memory and 64 cores. I'm using Spark 1.5.0 in stand alone mode. My program reads data from Oracle tables using JDBC, then does ETL, manipulating data, and does machine learning tasks like k-means.

I have a DataFrame (myDF.cache()) which is join results with two other DataFrames, and cached. The DataFrame contains 27 million rows and the size of data is around 1.5G. I need to filter the data and calculate 24 histogram as follows:

```scala
val h1 = myDF.filter("pmod(idx, 24) = 0").select("col1").histogram(arrBucket) 
val h2 = myDF.filter("pmod(idx, 24) = 1").select("col1").histogram(arrBucket) 
// ...... 
val h24 = myDF.filter("pmod(idx, 24) = 23").select("col1").histogram(arrBucket)
```

Problems:

1. Since my DataFrame is cached, I expect the filter, select, and histogram is very fast. However, the actual time is about 7 seconds for each calculation, which is not acceptable. From UI, it show the GC time takes 5 seconds and Task Deserialization Time 4 seconds. I've tried different JVM parameters but cannot improve further. Right now I'm using

   ```
   -Xms25G -Xmx25G -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 \
   -XX:ParallelGCThreads=32 \
   -XX:ConcGCThreads=8 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70
   ```

What puzzles me is that the size of data is nothing compared with available memory. Why does GC kick in every time filter/select/histogram running? Is there any way to reduce the GC time and Task Deserialization Time?

2. I have to do parallel computing for h[1-24], instead of sequential. I tried Future, something like:

   ```scala
   import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future, blocking} 

   import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global 

   val f1  = Future{myDF.filter("pmod(idx, 24) = 1").count} 
   val f2  = Future{myDF.filter("pmod(idx, 24) = 2").count} 
   val f3  = Future{myDF.filter("pmod(idx, 24) = 3").count} 

   val future = for {c1 <- f1; c2 <- f2; c3 <- f3} yield { 
     c1 + c2 + c3 
   } 

   val summ = Await.result(future, 180 second)
   ```

The problem is that here Future only means jobs are submitted to the scheduler near-simultaneously, not that they end up being scheduled and run simultaneously. Future used here doesn't improve performance at all.

How to make the 24 computation jobs run simultaneously?

Comment: GCs depend on allocation rates. so attach a profiler and profile object allocations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things you can try:

1. Don't compute `pmod(idx, 24)` all over again. Instead you can simply compute it once:

   ```scala
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{pmod, lit}

   val myDfWithBuckets = myDF.withColumn("bucket", pmod($"idx", lit(24)))
   ```
2. Use `SQLContext.cacheTable` instead of `cache`. It stores table using compressed columnar storage which can be used to access only required columns and as stated in the [Spark SQL and DataFrame Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#caching-data-in-memory) "*will automatically tune compression to minimize memory usage and GC pressure*".

   ```scala
   myDfWithBuckets.registerTempTable("myDfWithBuckets")
   sqlContext.cacheTable("myDfWithBuckets")
   ```
3. If you can, cache only the columns you actually need instead of projecting each time.
4. It is not clear for me what is the source of a `histogram` method (do you convert to `RDD[Double]` and use `DoubleRDDFunctions.histogram`?) and what is the argument but if you want to compute all histograms at the same time you can try to `groupBy` bucket and apply histogram once for example using `histogram_numeric` UDF:

   ```scala
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.callUDF

   val n: Int = ???

   myDfWithBuckets
     .groupBy($"bucket")
     .agg(callUDF("histogram_numeric", $"col1", lit(n)))
   ```

   If you use predefined ranges you can obtain a similar effect using custom UDF.

**Notes**

- how to extract values computed by `histogram_numeric`? First lets create a small helper

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

  def extractBuckets(xs: Seq[Row]): Seq[(Double, Double)] =
    xs.map(x => (x.getDouble(0), x.getDouble(1)))
  ```

  now we can map using pattern matching as follows:

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

  val histogramsRDD: RDD[(Int, Seq[(Double, Double)])] = histograms.map{
    case Row(k: Int, hs: Seq[Row @unchecked]) => (k, extractBuckets(hs)) }
  ```

Comment: Did you run into the error with histogramsRDD: "object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, value: 'histogram_numeric(x1,3) AS x1#5)"?

Comment: Let me guess - `spark-shell` or another interactive session?

Comment: Your guess is correct - I'm using spark-shell. I'll try spark-submit later.

Comment: Yeah, this is a common problem and surprisingly hard to reproduce. For some reason column definitions can be included in a closure and everything fails. I've been thinking about opening JIRA for that but somehow I cannot reproduce the problem when I need that.

Comment: @zero323 Actually, from the doc you point at, I read that dataFrame.cache() is equivalent to cacheTable.